# material ui TextField variant outlined, problem with react-seles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

hello i have a problem because, like you can see in the image, when i use react-select and textfiled with variant="outlined" because the label of the textfield shows itself even over the option, there is a class or something to solve  this?

[image]

```
<TextField
    variant="outlined"
     label="First Name"
  />
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a zIndex on the `<TextField`:

```
      <TextField
        label="Points"
        type="number"
        min={1}
        max={999}
        value={props.question.value}
        disabled={!props.question.expanded}
        onChange={ev => props.updateValue(props.ix, ev.target.value)}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true,
        }}
        variant="outlined"
        style={{ width: '5em', zIndex: -1 }}
        margin="dense"
        fullWidth
      />
```